# In html5 server sent event, why do I see polling log on fiddler

Tags: html

I am not able to figure out that why do I see polling log in fiddler for the server sent event I am trying to implement using HTML 5. Please find the image of my fiddler log below

[image]

If its server sent event, the message should be sent from server without system calling the method again and again to look for updates. Or i have not implemented it properly. Here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
var userStatusChangeEvent = new EventSource("/events");
userStatusChangeEvent.onmessage = function (event) {
    data = $.parseJSON(event.data);

    for (index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        $elem = $('#' + data[index].Id);
        isOnline = data[index].IsOnline;

        if (isOnline) {
            $elem.addClass('is_online');
            $('.loginTimestamp', $elem).html(data[index].Time);
        }
        else {
            $elem.removeClass('is_online');
            $('.loginTimestamp', $elem).html('');
        }
    }
};
});
</script>


public virtual ActionResult Events()
    {
        var userStream = new UserServerSentStatusResult();
        userStream.ChangeUserStatus = new LoggedUsersViewModel().Users.Where(x => x.HasChanged).ToList();

        userStream.Content = () =>
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(userStream.ChangeUserStatus);
        };

        userStream.ChangeUserStatus.ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.HasChanged = false;
            x.Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        });
        return userStream;
    }
```

Comment: Please, show your server-side code

Comment: please see the controlled action ...

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the [Streaming mode](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/streaming.asp) in Fiddler